# Python LSTM Bitcoin prediction flatlines

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm currently trying to build a "simple" LSTM model that takes historical Bitcoin data, learns from that and then tries to predict the future X steps in advance.

I've build it on the idea that A + B + C = D so B + C + D should be E. (I think that's a very simple idea behind an LSTM model. I might be wrong however i'm pretty new to it.)

I managed to build the basics in python (I'm fairly new to python) but something seems off by the prediction. For some reason many of the predictions i test / make end up flatlining. I have a theory on why but we have no idea if it's correct and even less idea on how to solve it.

My theory is that within a sequence the model learns to put more importance / weight on the last digit in the sequence because with Bitcoin prices the future price (in 1 minute) is probably pretty close to the price now. That's try the predicted values keeps getting closer to the real value eventually being equal and thus flatlining in a graph. (I don't know if that makes sense but thats what i tought anyway.)

I've also added a screenshot of my graph from a few days ago. Almost all predictions however end similar to this graph. This is just a more extreme example as demonstration.

[image: As seen, at first it seems to predict alright but then starts flatlining it's prediction.]

Here is my code, can someone please explain why it flatlines and what i did wrong?

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
import yfinance as yf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Create output sets X + Y from given input-set
#    with inputset : a 1-dimensional list of floats
#    with  N :  the number of lookback values to use for X
#    with Gap : the number of point skipped between X and Y
#    Y: is equal to input, (although the first N are missing)
#    X: for each y of Y a corresponding  set of size N is created
#        composed of the N values preceeding y.
def create_lookback(inputset, n=1, gap=0):
    print("create_lookback with n=%d gap=%d" % (n,gap))
    print(" - length of inputset = %d" % len(inputset))
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(inputset) - (n+gap)):
        a = inputset[i:(i + n), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(inputset[i + n+gap, 0])
    print(" - length of dataY = %d" % len(dataY))
    data_x = np.array(dataX)
    xret = data_x.reshape(data_x.shape[0], 1, data_x.shape[1])
    return xret, np.array(dataY)

# Train model based on given training-set + Test-set
def create_model(trainX,trainY,testX,testY):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(units = 100, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2], )))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    #model.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=5, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    return model

#  Evaluate given X / Y set.
#   - Calculate RMSE
#   - Generate visual line-plot to screen
def show_result(scaler,yhat,setY,txt):
    print("Show %s result" % txt)

    yhat_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(yhat.reshape(-1, 1))
    testY_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(setY.reshape(-1, 1))
    if len(testY_inverse) == len(yhat_inverse):
        rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY_inverse, yhat_inverse))
        print(' RMSE %s : %.3f' % (txt,rmse))
    pyplot.plot(yhat_inverse, label='predict '+txt)
    pyplot.plot(testY_inverse, label='actual '+txt, alpha=0.5)
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.show()

# Extrapoleer is dutch for Extrapolate
def extrapoleer(i,model,tup,toekomst):
    if(i == 0):
        return
    setX = np.array([[tup]])
    y = model.predict(setX)
    y_float = y[0][0]
    tup_new = np.append(tup[1:], y_float)
    toekomst.append(y_float)
    extrapoleer(i-1, model, tup_new,toekomst)


# --- end of defined functions

# -- start of main flow
data_grid_1 = yf.download('BTC-USD', start="2021-04-14",end="2021-04-15", interval="1m");
data_grid_2 = yf.download('BTC-USD', period="12h", interval="1m");
dataset_1 = data_grid_1.iloc[:, 1:2].values
dataset_2 = data_grid_2.iloc[:, 1:2].values



scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_1)

# 70% of dataset_1 is used to train ; 30% to test
train_size = int(len(scaled) * 0.7)
test_size = len(scaled) - train_size
train, test = scaled[0:train_size,:], scaled[train_size:len(scaled),:]
print("train: %d  test: %d" % (len(train), len(test)))
scaled_2 = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_2)

look_back_n = 3
look_back_gap = 0

trainX, trainY = create_lookback(train, look_back_n, look_back_gap)
testX, testY = create_lookback(test, look_back_n, look_back_gap)


testX_2, testY_2 = create_lookback(scaled_2, look_back_n, look_back_gap)

    
model = create_model(trainX,trainY,testX,testY)
yhat_1 = model.predict(testX)
yhat_2 = model.predict(testX_2)
show_result(scaler,yhat_1,testY,"test")
show_result(scaler,yhat_2,testY_2,"test2")

    
last_n = testY_2[-look_back_n:]

#toekomst = Future in dutch
toekomst = []
#aantal = Amount in Dutch, this indicates the amount if steps you want to future predict
aantal = 30
extrapoleer(aantal, model, last_n, toekomst)
print("Resultaat van %d voorspelde punten in de toekomst: " % aantal)
print(toekomst)

yhat_2_plus = np.append(yhat_2,toekomst)
show_result(scaler,yhat_2_plus,testY_2,"test2-plus")
```